# Retrieving only type of the geometry error by using validateGeometry() in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, validation, self-intersection

I have a polygon layer and I am trying to catch the geometry error by using [`validateGeometry()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.validateGeometry). The following snippet is working and finding the reason for the error as well as the location.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

for current, inFeat in enumerate(features):
    geom = inFeat.geometry()
    if not geom.isNull() and not geom.isEmpty():
        errors = list(geom.validateGeometry())
        if errors:
            print(inFeat['ID'], errors)

            reasons = []
            for error in errors:
                errFeat = QgsFeature()
                error_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(error.where())
                reasons.append(error.what())
```

My error message with the snippet looks like this

> ['segments 4 and 6 of line 0 intersect at 357246.699102,
> 385179.300166', 'segments 4 and 8 of line 0 intersect at 357252.065605, 385179.208431']

However, I would like to have the error message similar [Check Validity Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/it/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools.html) which shows the error as in the image only the type of the error e.g. Self-intersection

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: An interesting question ... I could not find something similar to *'Self-Intersection'* in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ltr-3_10/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/CheckValidity.py

Comment: @GermánCarrillo, can person choose which message of which validation dialect to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get using `QgsGeometry.validateGeometry()` depends on the validity method you choose.

If you choose `QGIS validation`, you'll get messages like the one you copied in your question, whereas if you choose `GEOS validation`, you'll get error messages like in the screenshot you posted.

`QGIS validation` is the default validation for `QgsGeometry.validateGeometry()`. Switch to `GEOS validation` in this way:

```
geom.validateGeometry(QgsGeometry.ValidatorGeos)
```

You can read the list of error messages per validation method here:

- [Error messages using QGIS validation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=check%20validity#id251).
- [Error messages using GEOS validation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=check%20validity#id250).